# Copy file name and path in Sublime

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have tried to find command, plugin or anything that can do this. Essentially I need two keyboard shortcuts. One to copy current file path(only current directory, not file name). Another to copy only file name(with extension eg; "test.txt" ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple plugin such as this (see this [video on using plugins in Sublime](https://youtu.be/lBgDilqulxg) if you're not sure how to put it in place):

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

import os


class CopyFilePathCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, name=False):
        path, filename = os.path.split(self.view.file_name())

        sublime.set_clipboard(filename if name else path)
        self.view.window().status_message(
            'Copied file %s' % ("name" if name else "path"))

    def is_enabled(self, name=False):
        return self.view.file_name() is not None
```

This implements a command named `copy_file_path` which will copy the path of the current file to the clipboard by default, switching to copying the name of the file instead if you pass `true` for the value of the `name` argument.

A message is displayed in the status bar to tell you which thing was copied, and the command will disable itself for any file that hasn't been saved to disk yet (since it would thus have no path to copy).

Sample key bindings might look something like the following:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+alt+p"], "command": "copy_file_path", "args": {"name": false}},
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+alt+f"], "command": "copy_file_path", "args": {"name": true}},
```

Comment: Thanks xD. But for some reason copy file name will not work with `ctrl+shift+alt+f` and its working fine when I assign another shortcut to it.

Comment: That's usually an indication that something external might be eating the key before Sublime sees it, or it reads as not the key you think. In the Sublime console you can `sublime.log_commands(True)` and/or sublime.log_input(True)`; that will log whenever you press a key and whenever a command executes. You can use that to see if Sublime is seeing the key, and if so what it's seeing it as, and how it's reacting to what yo udid.